# How to remove unnecessary characters from this kind of string?

Tags: python, regex, control-characters, color-codes

```
[1mResolving domain yahoo.com ,[0m ,98.138.253.109  yahoo.com
```

I want to remove `"[1m"` and `"[0m"`. I tried encoding using `encode('utf-8')` didn't worked.

Please help.

Comment: How can those characters be identified?

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you're receiving a color-coded string from a VT100-compatible terminal. There should be #27 (0x1b, ESC) symbols in the string, if so, use the regexp eliminating color codes starting with ESC symbols from the string. You can check the possible list of color codes [in this Wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Sorry I'm not an expert to write a regexp or Python code, so please use other answers for codes.

Answer (score 1):

There's too little information in the question, but I think the following should do it:

```
import re
s = '[1mResolving domain yahoo.com ,[0m ,98.138.253.109    yahoo.com'
t = re.sub('\[\dm', '', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a="[1mResolving domain yahoo.com ,[0m ,98.138.253.109  yahoo.com"
c=["[1m","[0m"]
for i in c:
  a=a.replace(i,"")
print a
```

if you want remove any more ,you can add it to list c